# Why does my toilet still leak after replacing the wax ring?

Tags: plumbing, leak, toilet

I just replaced the wax ring under my toilet. Now when you flush, it leaks worse than it did before! I am so confused! Is there something else that needs to be replaced?

Comment: Have you determined where the leak occurs?  Did you clean the old wax off completely before replacing?  Did you use the right size ring?

Comment: And did you install the new ring correctly? Only pushing down, not rocking to the side or pulling up?

Comment: yes I believe that may have found the issue I found a tile under the toilet protruding over another tile and I think that maybe it is not allowing the toilet to sit flush on the floor! is there a way to seal the toilet without having to rip up the tile?

Comment: use two wax rings, but be sure toilet is sitting flush on the floor.  Is your flange much lower than the tile level?

Comment: How much higher is the one tile above the other?

Answer (score 1):

As alluded to by 'The Evil Greebo', there is an oversize (thicker) wax ring readily available. Make sure there are no obstructions on the toilet flange and bottom of the toilet.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against using 2 wax rings due to the increased possibility of leaks.  Short of hiring a plumber to raise the flange, there are products like this that allow you to raise the flange and still follow building codes.

[image: Extension kit]